# User gone rogue

Tags: discussion, specific-user, new-users

[This user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/31235/doit) has been asking a series of ill-formatted question showing no effort whatsoever, and he (or she) does not even seem to answer any comment posted. Moreover, at least one question has been asked [multiple times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151226/show-that-for-a-twice-differentiable-function-f-lim-h-to-0-fracfa2h). I think it is fair to qualify the actions of this user as inappropriate, and in opposition to MathSE's values (to say the least). My question: what should we do? Do we simply ignore its questions (this doesn't seem very constructive)? Should the user be banned for some time? What are your suggestions?

Comment: So much for not naming names! (I couldn't care less; identifying a user by their [user]name is just an inconsistently supported/opposed practice on meta...)

Comment: What is interesting is how he has been a member for 17 days (and even asked a question a few days ago.)  You would think he would pick up some of the rules over time, since two and a half weeks is a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: I think there are also some automated features of the platform that eventually block a user from asking questions entirely if they consistently post low-quality questions, but the exact metrics for it are not public, since that could facilitate gaming the system.

Comment: @Isaac That automatic system is only active on a few sites, it is not enabled here as far as I know.

Comment: @MadScientist: Yeah, I think you're right... though if it's active on even a few sites, I'd expect it to be active here—based on [this](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), we're the third-busiest SE site by rate at which questions are asked, behind only SO and AskUbuntu.

Comment: We're behind AskUbuntu? Man...I hadn't realised free-loading was so popular!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The user has been suspended for 7 days. This is the standard length of time for a first serious issue (and this qualifies as a serious issue).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the standard protocol for this situation is to let the moderators suspend (or not) the user. Is there something a non-moderator like can or should do?

Comment: There are various things you can do: leave a helpful comment, downvote, vote to close if it gets bad, and flag a moderator if it gets really bad.

Comment: So this is the user's first suspension? The previous time they stopped asking questions for a while (and the same questions were reasked by a [different account](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/31808/nana), I assumed this was due to a suspension.